# C# - What's wrong with my conversion from double to int?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I keep getting this error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("ISBN-Prüfziffer berechnen");
Console.WriteLine("=========================");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("ISBN-Nummer ohne Prüfziffer: ");
string ISBNstring = Console.ReadLine();
int ISBN = Convert.ToInt32(ISBNstring);
int PZ;
int i;
double x = Math.Pow(3, (i + 1) % 2);
int y = (int)x;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    PZ = ((10-(PZ + ISBN * x) % 10) % 10);
}
Console.WriteLine(PZ);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the new code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("ISBN-Prüfziffer berechnen");
Console.WriteLine("=========================");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("ISBN-Nummer ohne Prüfziffer: ");
string ISBNstring = Console.ReadLine();
long ISBN = Convert.ToInt32(ISBNstring);
long ISBN1 = (Int64)ISBN;
int PZ = 0;
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    double x = Math.Pow(3, (i + 1) % 2);
    long y = (double)x;
    PZ = ((10 - (PZ + ISBN * y) % 10) % 10);
}
Console.WriteLine(PZ);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I'm still getting a conversion error for double to long and long to int...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you meant to use your `y` variable here instead of `x` :

```
PZ = ((10-(PZ + ISBN * y) % 10) % 10);
```

As a side note, you'll get compilation errors on both `PZ` and `i`, you need to initialize their values before using them, e.g. `int PZ = 0;` and `int i = 0;`

And please, use meaningful names; `PZ`, `i`, `x` and `y` don't mean anything to someone reading your code, or even to you in a few weeks.

---

Okay, I've modified it a little...

```
Console.WriteLine("ISBN-Prüfziffer berechnen");
Console.WriteLine("=========================");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("ISBN-Nummer ohne Prüfziffer: ");
string ISBNstring = Console.ReadLine();

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    int digit = ISBNstring[i] - '0';
    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        digit *= 3;
    }
    sum += digit;
}
int result = 10 - (sum%10);

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here's the changes : 
- You can declare i directly in your for loop, it'll save you a line.
- Instead of putting the ISBN into a long, keep in in a string. Just iterate over each character one by one.
- Each digit can be obtained by taking the ASCII value, and removing the value of 0.
- The `% 2 == 1` thing is basically "If the number is at an odd position", where you can apply the *3. This replaces your `Math.Pow` that wasn't very clear.

Comment: Spot on, deleted my answer

Comment: @Bradoff, just a minor addition to the answer. It looks like that the calculation of x (and y respectively) should happen within the loop, or?

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone now. But for some reason the code doesn't work as I thought it would.

Comment: @Bradoff, look at my comment above. That's perhaps why it's not working as expected...

Comment: You also do not assign a value to `i` before you use it in the `Math.Pow`

Comment: @Bradolf Can't help you much for the behaviour of your code. I don't know the expected output and the whole code is pretty.. let's say cryptic. Your best bet would be to break down the algorithm and make some unit tests. Or set up some breakpoints and debug it by hand.

Comment: Thanks I already read and applied it, but it's still not working. What I'm supposed to do is enter a 12-digit number and the formula was supposed to add and multiply each digit by 1 and 3 respectively. Now whenever I enter a 12-digit number it says that the number is too large for int32?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Yeah sorry about that, I'm new to programming.

Comment: @Bradolf that's because `int` max value is 2 147 483 647. Use a `long` instead to store a 12 digit number

Comment: This is the max size for an int `2,147,483,647.`

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Ok thanks, I tried to convert it now and I'm getting another error... int ISBN = Convert.ToInt32(ISBNstring);
            int ISBN1 = (long)ISBN; I also tried to do int ISBN = Convert.ToInt64 but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Bradolf Since it's 12 digits long, you'll need to always stick to `long` instead of `int`, don't try to convert it back. See it as a "big int". So you can use `Convert.ToInt64()` to create the `long`, and replace your `int` casts with `long` casts. Don't forget to put PZ as a long too.

Comment: @Bradolf By the way, what you need to do is multiply each digits by alternatively 1 and 3? Is that correct? And what happens if you have for example 29[...], it gives 227[...] and a 13 digit number?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Thanks for being patient. Yes that's what I need to do. I have to multiply each digit by 1 and 3 alternatively. The output is actually supposed to be a single digit number. Here is an example: 978-3-446-42118-9 ->  9+7*3+8+3*3+4+4*3+6+4*3+2+1*3+1+8*3 = 111 -> 111 mod 10 = 1   10-1= 9

Comment: @Bradolf alright wait a few mins, I'll figure out what's wrong with your algorithm

Comment: @Bradolf, you should iterate over the **characters** of the ISBN string to treat the digits individually. Something like this: `foreach (char c in ISBN) { if c >= '0' && c <= '9' { int digit = ( int) c - '0'; ... and so on...  } } }`

Comment: @Brafolf Updated my answer with a working version. Sorry for the delay, was using all 13 numbers and stupidly wondered why the hell it didn't work :P

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Thank you so much! I'll try it out as soon as possible!

Comment: @Pierre, you don't need to do `int digit = Convert.ToInt32(ISBNstring[i] - '0');`. A simple `int digit = ISBNstring[i] - '0'` does it :)

Comment: @elgonzo Indeed! Thanks for pointing it out :) There's also char.GetNumericValue, but the need for an int cast (the method returns a long) is pretty annoying.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I just tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help!